# Can't append slice to existing slice

Tags: go

My goal below is to return a slice of slices, so I can iterate over them later in my main function.

The current behavior is the "test" variable will show each line in a slice when I print it at `fmt.PrintLn(test)`, but the "parsed" variable when printed at `fmt.PrintLn(showParsed)` is empty. How can I resolve that?

```
func lsCommand(outString string) []string {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(outString))
    var parsed []string
    for scanner.Scan() {
        s := scanner.Text()
        ss := strings.Fields(s)
        test := append(parsed, ss...)
        fmt.Println(test)
    }
    return parsed
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ok, outString, errString := runBashCommandAndKillIfTooSlow(ctx, "ls", 2000*time.Millisecond)
    if ok != true {
        panic(errString)
    }

    showParsed := lsCommand(outString)
    fmt.Println(showParsed)
}
```

Comment: How are you sure the problem is appending, and not that `s` , `ss`, or `outString` is not what you expect?

Comment: @Flimzy I can see during fmt.Println(test) that "test" prints each line, so I believe everything up to "ss" is good.

Comment: The problem is that you're assigning the result to `test`, which you then immediately discard.

Answer (score 1):

[`append` isn't guaranteed](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) to modify the slice passed to it, so `parsed` isn't changed.  Only `test` contains the elements of `ss`.  Use the returned value in each iteration:

```
var parsed []string
for scanner.Scan() {
    s := scanner.Text()
    ss := strings.Fields(s)
    parsed = append(parsed, ss...)
}
return parsed
```